# Will Microsoft ever call or email you for support or updates?

Tags: windows, phishing

I have had a couple of clients who got phished, one by email (regarding a fake Windows 7 upgrade) one by cell phone (we are Microsoft support please open a remote connection for us). This is the first time I've actually seen phishing (haven't really done virus support either).

My question is would Microsoft EVER call or email a home user personally? (pretty sure they won't but lets have a vote for the benefit of the non tech people reading this).

Comment: Microsoft does not have your phone number, they do not have your address, they know nothing about you.  While Microsoft does offers support for their operating system, they do not offer support with infections, only problems directly linked to their products.  This sort of scam has been popular for at least the last 5 years.  Microsoft does not offer "free" upgrades to customers, it just doesn't happen, get new clients :-)

Comment: the clients are friends and relations, actually.... she already had windows 7 though, but did not know it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no need for a vote or for speculation. Microsoft are quite clear about their policy for contacting customers by phone - they state that they don't ever make unsolicited calls of that sort.

According to http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/security/online-privacy/msname.aspx

> #### Avoid scams that use the Microsoft name fraudulently
>
> **Common scams that use the Microsoft name**
>
> - Someone from "Microsoft Tech Support" calls to fix your computer
>
> **Avoid these dangerous hoaxes**
>
> If you receive an unsolicited email message or phone call that purports to 
>   be from Microsoft and requests that you send personal
>   information or click links, delete the message or hang up the phone..
>
> **Microsoft does not make unsolicited phone calls to help you fix your
>   computer**
>
> In this scam cybercriminals call you and claim to be from Microsoft Tech Support. They offer to help solve your computer
>   problems. Once the crooks have gained your trust, they attempt to
>   steal from you and damage your computer with malicious software
>   including viruses and spyware.
>
> Treat all unsolicited phone calls with skepticism. Do not provide any
>   personal information
>
> If you receive an unsolicited call from someone claiming to be from
>   Microsoft Tech Support, hang up. We do not make these kinds of calls.

Answer (score 13):

Microsoft will never call if you did not call first.

This is a well known scam in US and Canada at least and is designed to gain access or banking info (or both).

See the end of the ["Telemarketing fraud"](http://enwp.org/Telemarketing_fraud) Wikipedia article for information on what to do if you've already been scammed. Hint: You should reinstall.

Comment: ....and the UK, and Spain....

Comment: Add the Netherlands! I've been called, but it was very obvious: that guy barely spoke English and actually asked me if I had a Windows computer!